# mysql distinct on part of the column result

Tags: mysql

How to use mysql distinct on part of the column result.

```
SELECT distinct (groupname) FROM custom_quotes.compatibility_rule where groupname like '%_Sol%';
```

Current Results:-

```
Acetone_Sol : 1
Acetone_Sol : 10
Acetone_Sol : 1000
Water_Sol : 9596
Water_Sol : 9597
Isopropanol_Sol : 4074
Isopropanol_Sol : 4075
Isopropanol_Sol : 4076
```

Expected :

```
Acetone_Sol :
Water_Sol : 
Isopropanol_Sol :
```

**Actual data:**

[image]

Comment: I don't think the current results could be the result of the query in the question. Where are the numbers coming from?

Comment: Thx, that is the actual data mate on DB.

Comment: Ah, I see... that wasn't obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try using `SUBSTRING_INDEX` here:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(groupname, ':', 1), ':') AS groupname_distinct
FROM custom_quotes.compatibility_rule
WHERE groupname LIKE '%\_Sol%';
```

`SUBSTRING_INDEX` works above by taking the substring to the left of the first occurrence of `:`, which is the separator between the text and numeric portions of the group names.

Answer (score 3):

You can use left() to get the part of the column without the number:

```
SELECT distinct left(groupname, locate(':', groupname)) 
FROM custom_quotes.compatibility_rule 
where groupname like '%#_Sol%' ESCAPE '#';
```

You also need to escape the underscore in `'%_Sol%'` because it is a wild char for `LIKE`.

Comment: Good catch on the underscore inside `LIKE` +1.  I used a backslash.  Note that you might want to adjust your call to `LEFT` by one position, to remove the whitespace in between the `:` and the text group names.

Comment: I'm not sure about that. It seems that the OP wants `:` in the expected results.